# setting the ScriptManager AsyncPostBackTimeout value on the ASP.NET content page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, timeout, master-pages, scriptmanager

I am using Master pages for my ASP.NET website and in one of the content pages I upload a file which requires a bigger timeout value than the default 90 seconds. For other content pages I want to leave the default timeout value as it is.

Is it possible to set the timeout just for a specific content page? I checked the ScriptManagerProxy component, but it doesn't have a AsyncPostBackTimeout property.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to set it in your code-behind in the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 300;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I don't understand why this property is not available on ScriptManagerProxy so this property can be set in the mark-up, not in Page_load event handler.